# O formulário não está sendo salvo no BD

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Controller

```
public function cadastro()
{
    return View('/cadastro');
}

public function novo()
{        
    $user = \App\User::where('User',"=", Input::get("User"))->first();

            $user->name = Input::get('name');
            $user->host = Input::get('host');
            $user->login = Input::get('login');
            $user->password = hash('sha256', Input::get('password'));
            $user->save($user);

}
```

Rotas

```
Route::get('cadastro', 'Auth\RegisterController@cadastro');
Route::post('cadastro', 'Auth\RegisterController@novo');
```

View

```
<body>        

<section method="POST" action="cadastro/novo">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <h1><b>CADASTRE SUA EMPRESA!</b></h1>
        <hr>        
    </nav>  
    <div id="area">
        <form id="formulario">       
            <fieldset style = "width: 200%; margin: 0px auto;">                    
                        <img src="/imagens/cliente.png" width="60px" height="60px" required/>
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="name" placeholder="Nome:" required><br>
                        <input type="text" name="host" class="host" placeholder="Host:" required><br>
                        <input type="text" name="email" class="email" placeholder="Email:" required><br>
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="senha" placeholder="Senha:" required>
                        <legend><input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" onclick="return change(this);"/></legend>                    
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>    

</section>

 <img class="canto" src="/imagens/unius.png"/>    

 <footer>
    <p>Desenvolvido por: Vitória</p>
</footer>
```

Model User

```
    class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email','password','tipo'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token', 'tipo'
    ];

    public function clients ()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\client', 'client_user');  
    }

    class clientUser extends Model
    {
        public $timestamps = false;
    }
}
```

Tabela clients: Essa é a minha tabela de clientes, que é onde estou com dificuldade, pq o formulário não está salvando nela.

Tabela users: Onde estão os meus usuários.

Tabela clienteUser: Onde faz a relação das duas tabelas... Quem é usuário administrador seleciona quais os clientes que os usuários desenvolvedores podem ver.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

View de cadastro!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Está acontecendo algum erro? isso seria um registro de cadastro novo?

Comment: Não dá erro, só não salva no BD! E sim, é um registro novo que deveria salvar numa tabela.

Comment: Você está usando Eloquent?

Comment: Sim, estou!!!!!!

Comment: Fiz uma resposta te ajudou @Vitoria?

Comment: Mais ou menos @Virgilio.. Dá esse erro "ErrorException in Model.php line 485:
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::save() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\Users\Vit�ria\Desktop\Projeto\projeto\app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php on line 189 and defined" dai se eu tento colocar um timestamps no model, dá erro esse erro: "syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)"

Comment: Coloque sua cosas User na pergunta

Comment: Já coloquei o código!

Comment: Você colocou a classe `clientUser` dentro da `User`, está errado isso também e um usuário pode ser vários ClientesUser? Olha a sua programação que está errada primeiramente e por isso de tantos problemas!

Comment: Pode ser sim. Pq é uma tabela de relacionamento no MySQL.

Comment: Faz o seguinte Vitória coloque o layout dessas duas tabelas com os relacionamentos na sua pergunta, eu consigo gerar os models e te posicionar melhor, se quiser é claro...

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Coloquei as tabelas!

Comment: Eu coloquei uma resposta se viu Vitória?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic N resolveu para mim!

Answer (score 0):

Você está tentando buscar um campo que não consta no formulário.

> Input::get("User");

Se é um novo usuário, você deve criar uma nova instância, por exemplo:

```
$user = new \App\User;

$user->name = Input::get('name');
$user->host = Input::get('host');
$user->login = Input::get('login');
$user->password = hash('sha256', Input::get('password'));

$user->save($user);
```

Comment: Não foi :( Fica do mesmo jeito!

Comment: Tente apenas "$user->save()"; Se não der certo, antes do "$user->save($user);", coloque "echo $user; die;" sem as aspas e poste aqui o que é retornado.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'User' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Comment: O erro agora está no Model

Comment: Nesse comando: "class User extends Model ()
    {
        public $timestamps = false;
    }"

Answer (score 0):

Tem muitos erros começando pelo `method` e `action` nos lugares errados eles devem ficar contidos na `tag` `<form>`, como exemplo abaixo:

***Html: `View`***

```
<section>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <h1><b>CADASTRE SUA EMPRESA!</b></h1>
        <hr>        
    </nav>  
    <div id="area">
        <form id="formulario" method="POST" action="/cadastro/novo">       
            <fieldset style = "width: 200%; margin: 0px auto;">                    
                <img src="/imagens/cliente.png" width="60px" height="60px" required/>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="name" placeholder="Nome:" required><br>
                <input type="text" name="host" class="host" placeholder="Host:" required><br>
                <input type="text" name="email" class="email" placeholder="Email:" required><br>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="senha" placeholder="Senha:" required>
                <legend><input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" onclick="return change(this);"/></legend>                    
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>    
</section>
 <img class="canto" src="/imagens/unius.png"/>    
 <footer>
    <p>Desenvolvido por: Vitória</p>
</footer>
```

Na parte das rotas são assim:

```
Route::get('cadastro', 'Auth\RegisterController@cadastro');
Route::post('cadastro/novo', 'Auth\RegisterController@novo');
```

E no métodos do `controller`:

```
public function cadastro()
{
    return View('/cadastro');
}

public function novo()
{        
    $user = new \App\User();
    $user->name = Input::get('name');
    $user->host = Input::get('host');
    $user->login = Input::get('login');
    $user->password = hash('sha256', Input::get('password'));
    $user->save();
}
```

Essa é a forma básica, não estou levando em conta redirecionamentos, mas, assim basicamente deveria salvar as informações, apesar que tem o campo `email` na `view` que não está sendo usado no método do `controller`, então pode ter mais erros ai !!!

***@Edit***

Seriam 3 classes para representar o seu modelo de base de dados, e cada uma gravando e sua determinada tabela, dessa forma precisa expor a tabela intermediária e pode ser feitas as operações normalmente:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = "users";
    protected $primaryKey = "id";
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email','password','tipo'];
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];   

    public function ClientUser()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ClientUser::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    } 

}

class Client extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = "id";
    protected $table = "clients";  

    public function ClientUser()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ClientUser::class, 'client_id', 'id');
    }      
}

class ClientUser extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = "id";
    protected $table = "client_user"; 
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'client_id'];   
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function User()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'user_id');
    }

    public function Client()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Client::class, 'id', 'client_id');
    }
}
```

Agora só criar as rotas e as páginas (`Views`) para cada model e salve os dados.